# bash profile not sourced when using exec for launching a script

Tags: bash, posix

For technical reason I have to launch a script setting the GROUP ID with which the script it's executed, like this:

```sh
exec sg group_name script
```

The script is using some functions source by .bashrc, everything is working fine if I launch the script directly, but when I use exec sg the sourced functions are not available.

Comment: That's completely normal; `.bash_profile` is only documented and expected to be invoked for login shells. `sg`, by contrast, isn't documented to invoke a child shell _at all_.

Comment: `.bash_profile` should only be used for things that are exported into the environment (you can export functions, not just variables). Use `BASH_ENV` to specify a script you want noninteractive shells to run on startup (that's a bash-only extension, the POSIX/standard environment variable for that purpose is named `ENV`, but bash only honors it when running in POSIX mode since folks so widely abuse the original variable name -- which the standard reserves for that purpose alone -- for other uses).

Comment: ...anyhow, what are you doing using `.bash_profile` to define contents you use from a script in the first place? Shell libraries should be in _libraries_ you can source explicitly (`source utils.bash`); interactive shell configuration files are for interactive user environments; users should be able to configure their interactive shell the way they like without worrying that it'll break scripts as a side effect (unless they explicitly `export` changes or modify a variable that's already present in the environment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bash_profile` is only sourced for *login* shells. A shell invoked with a command line passed to it is not a login shell; a shell invoked as a script interpreter is *also* not a login shell.

If you want a file to be sourced by non-login, non-interactive copies of bash (specifically), put the name of that file in the environment variable `BASH_ENV`. To do the same for strictly POSIX-compliant shells (or bash running in POSIX compatibility mode), use the name `ENV` instead.

Thus:

```
cat >yourscript.bash <<'EOF'
somefunc() { whatever; }
EOF

export BASH_ENV=$PWD/yourscript.bash

exec sg group_name yourscript
```

...and `yourscript` will be able to run `somefunc`.

But as a matter of practice, it's better not to do that; instead, make `yourscript` explicitly source whatever libraries define the functions it needs, so its operational behavior is independent of which user invokes it.